# How did the original tether iphone app share the phone's internet connection over USB?

Tags: iphone, ios, usb, tethering

Tethering to your iPhone over SOCKS is clunky and prone to errors. There was once an app published by tether.com that allowed users to share their 3g/4g/LTE internet connection with their mac over USB. I think this would be a worthwhile open source project. Trying to figure out if this would be possible.

Comment: This YC thread provides some insights: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3686368